# Changing the name of a YUM repository (or aliasing it)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, yum, amazon-ami, vestacp

I'm trying to install Vesta panel on Amazon Red Hat AMI.

At [some point of install script](https://github.com/serghey-rodin/vesta/blob/master/install/vst-install-rhel.sh#L616) Vesta try to install its software:

```
yum -y --disablerepo=* --enablerepo="*base,*updates,nginx,epel,vesta" \
        install $software
```

... disabling all repository and enabling some like `*base` and `*updates`.

My AMI repositories are:

```
*epel/x86_64 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64
nginx/x86_64 nginx repo
rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7/x86_64 Red Hat Update Infrastructure 2.0 Client Configuration Server 7
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases/7Server/x86_64 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 (RPMs)
rhui-REGION-rhel-server-rh-common/7Server/x86_64 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 RH Common (RPMs)
vesta/x86_64 Vesta - cmmnt
```

Problem is vesta is disabling all repository - I think because it's assuming that requirements (i.e. `php-common`, which is in `rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7/x86_64`) are in the base repository.

Is there a way to rename the `rhui-REGION-client-config-server-7/x86_64` into `base` or make an alias to it?

EDIT: repository file item:

```
[rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases]
name=Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7 (RPMs)
mirrorlist=https://rhui2-cds01.REGION.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/mirror/content/dist/rhel/rhui/server/7/$releasever/$basearch/os
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-redhat-release
sslverify=1
sslclientkey=/etc/pki/rhui/content-rhel7.key
sslclientcert=/etc/pki/rhui/product/content-rhel7.crt
sslcacert=/etc/pki/rhui/cdn.redhat.com-chain.crt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (temporarily, I would suggest) change the ID of a repository by modifying the string in the square brackets (the 'heading' in the repo file). This string is actually called `repositoryid` in the `yum.conf(5)` man page.

In your case, you would change `[rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases]` to something like `[rhui-REGION-rhel-server-releases-base]`, which should do the trick.